Fundamental group calculations on wedges of circles and punctured plane
I want to calculate the fundemental group of the following spaces $X$:

Say $C_n=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon (x-n)^2+y^2=n^2\}$, and $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} C_n$.
Say $C_n=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon (x-n)^2+(y-\frac 13)^2=(\frac 13)^2\}$,$T=\{(x,0)\colon x\in \mathbb R\}$ is the $x-$ axis. $X=T\cup \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} C_n$.
$\mathbb R^2-\mathbb Z^2$.

In the first space, I want to show that this space is homotopy equivalant to $\wedge_{n\in\mathbb N} S^1_k$, $k$ for $k-$th circle. But I failed to construct the homotopy. Besides I have another problem:
I consider map $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \wedge_{k\in \mathbb N} S^1_k,(k+k\cos(2\pi x),k\sin(2\pi x))\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}_k\in S^1_k$. This is a bijective map. But I don't think it's a homeomorphism because I know that the domain is first countable and the range is not. Where does the continuity fail?
In the second space I want to use van Kampen's theorem. I pick $U_n$ as the small neighbourhood of $(n,0)$, and $V_n=(n-\frac 23,n+\frac 23)$, take $W_n=C_n\cup U_n\cup V_n$, and show that $\pi(W_n)=\mathbb Z$. Also by induction I could get finite union of $W_n$ have fundemental group of $\ast_{i=1}^m \mathbb Z$. But how could I get the countable case? On the other hand, I don't think it is the same as (1), but just putting $m$ to $\infty$ I get the same group.
In the third space I consider $U_{k,n}=(k-\frac 23,k+\frac 23)\times (n-\frac 23,n+\frac 23)$ and use van Kampen's theorem. I have the same problem about is it correct to just put $k,m$ to infinite.

This is a really interesting question. The reason that your first space is not homeomorphic to a countable wedge of circles is that in your first space, you can find a sequence of points converging to the origin such that the $n$-th point lies in the $n$-th circle. However, such a situation is impossible in a countable wedge of circles.

@Smiley1000 But it is. There clearly is a sequence of points converging to the origin in the countable wedge, and also the countable wedge is homeomorphic to $X$. Maybe you're mixing this up with "countably many circles aligned end-to-end," but in the wedge everything is joined to a single basepoint. But even then the two spaces are homotopy equivalent.

@BenSteffan "There clearly is a sequence of points converging to the origin in the countable wedge" I believe that this is false. Take any sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n \in S^1_n$ and $x_n \neq 0$. For each $n$, there is a neighbourhood $U_n$ of $0$ in $S^1_n$ not containing $x_n$. Let $U$ be the union of all the $U_n$. Then $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in the countable wedge of circles, but the sequence $x_n$ never lies in $U$. Hence $(x_n)_n$ does not converge to $0$.

@BenSteffan And, as Robert notes, the countable wedge of circles is not first countable ($0$ has no countable neighbourhood base), but any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is first countable, which already shows that the first space must be first countable and hence they are not homeomorphic.

For the first space $X$, the fundamental group is a subgroup of the projective limit of the sequence of free groups $\{F_n\}$ and homomorphisms $F_n\to F_m$ for $n>m$ which sends the generators $x_i$ for $i\le m$ to themselves and the rest to $1$. This was previously discussed on mse. And the explicit description of this group is here.
The other two examples are homotopy equivalent to connected infinite graphs. The fundamental group of such a graph is a free group whose generators are in 1-1 correspondence with the edges complementary to the edges in a maximal tree containing the basepoint. This can be proved by a variant of the Seifert-van Kampen theorem: if a space is a union of two simply connected open sets and their intersection has more than one component, then the fundamental group is free on the path components of the intersection which don't contain the basepoint. Alternatively you can decompose these spaces into an increasing union of compact chunks and then observe that any loop and any homotopy between loops must be contained in such a chunk. Hence the fundamental group of the total space is the union of the fundamental groups of these compact chunks.
